# Display heartbeat sensor's readings from python program in a Kivy label

Tags: python, kivy, sensors, kivy-language, heartbeat

I'm trying to display the values obtained from my heartbeat sensor in my Kivy App. I've tried using the data extraction method applied on the other sensors but it's not working for this sensor as it doesn't contain any functions.

I've tried multiple different approaches but they all haven't returned the desired output. Can someone please have a look at the sensor code and suggest some method to display the output in my kivy app.

**Heartbeatsensot.py**

```
import time
# Import the ADS1x15 module.
import Adafruit_ADS1x15


if __name__ == '__main__':

    adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1015()
    # initialization 
    GAIN = 2/3  
    curState = 0
    thresh = 525  # mid point in the waveform
    P = 512
    T = 512
    stateChanged = 0
    sampleCounter = 0
    lastBeatTime = 0
    firstBeat = True
    secondBeat = False
    Pulse = False
    IBI = 600
    rate = [0]*10
    amp = 100

    lastTime = int(time.time()*1000)

    # Main loop. use Ctrl-c to stop the code
    while True:
        # read from the ADC
        Signal = adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN)   #TODO: Select the correct ADC channel. I have selected A0 here
        curTime = int(time.time()*1000)

        sampleCounter += curTime - lastTime;      #                   # keep track of the time in mS with this variable
        lastTime = curTime
        N = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime;     #  # monitor the time since the last beat to avoid noise
        #print N, Signal, curTime, sampleCounter, lastBeatTime

        ##  find the peak and trough of the pulse wave
        if Signal < thresh and N > (IBI/5.0)*3.0 :  #       # avoid dichrotic noise by waiting 3/5 of last IBI
            if Signal < T :                        # T is the trough
              T = Signal;                         # keep track of lowest point in pulse wave 

        if Signal > thresh and  Signal > P:           # thresh condition helps avoid noise
            P = Signal;                             # P is the peak
                                                # keep track of highest point in pulse wave

          #  NOW IT'S TIME TO LOOK FOR THE HEART BEAT
          # signal surges up in value every time there is a pulse
        if N > 250 :                                   # avoid high frequency noise
            if  (Signal > thresh) and  (Pulse == False) and  (N > (IBI/5.0)*3.0)  :       
              Pulse = True;                               # set the Pulse flag when we think there is a pulse
              IBI = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime;         # measure time between beats in mS
              lastBeatTime = sampleCounter;               # keep track of time for next pulse

              if secondBeat :                        # if this is the second beat, if secondBeat == TRUE
                secondBeat = False;                  # clear secondBeat flag
                for i in range(0,10):             # seed the running total to get a realisitic BPM at startup
                  rate[i] = IBI;                      

              if firstBeat :                        # if it's the first time we found a beat, if firstBeat == TRUE
                firstBeat = False;                   # clear firstBeat flag
                secondBeat = True;                   # set the second beat flag
                continue                              # IBI value is unreliable so discard it


              # keep a running total of the last 10 IBI values
              runningTotal = 0;                  # clear the runningTotal variable    

              for i in range(0,9):                # shift data in the rate array
                rate[i] = rate[i+1];                  # and drop the oldest IBI value 
                runningTotal += rate[i];              # add up the 9 oldest IBI values

              rate[9] = IBI;                          # add the latest IBI to the rate array
              runningTotal += rate[9];                # add the latest IBI to runningTotal
              runningTotal /= 10;                     # average the last 10 IBI values 
              BPM = 60000/runningTotal;               # how many beats can fit into a minute? that's BPM!
              print ('BPM: {}'.format(BPM))

        if Signal < thresh and Pulse == True :   # when the values are going down, the beat is over
            Pulse = False;                         # reset the Pulse flag so we can do it again
            amp = P - T;                           # get amplitude of the pulse wave
            thresh = amp/2 + T;                    # set thresh at 50% of the amplitude
            P = thresh;                            # reset these for next time
            T = thresh;

        if N > 2500 :                          # if 2.5 seconds go by without a beat
            thresh = 512;                          # set thresh default
            P = 512;                               # set P default
            T = 512;                               # set T default
            lastBeatTime = sampleCounter;          # bring the lastBeatTime up to date        
            firstBeat = True;                      # set these to avoid noise
            secondBeat = False;                    # when we get the heartbeat back
            print ("no beats found")

        time.sleep(0.005)
```

** the kivy app that I'm trying to add the readings to**

**another.py file**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder






class MainScreen(Screen):
   pass

class ScreenThermo(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ScreenThermo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.displayHR, 10)


    def displayHR(self,dt):
        heartbeat = 'BPM: {}'.format(BPM)
        pulse = heartbeat
        self.manager.screen_thermo.ids.TempLabel.text = str(pulse)


    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.__init__()
        pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("heartk.kv")

class MenuApp(App):
    def build(self):
       return presentation 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MenuApp().run()
```

**.kv file**

```
ScreenManagement:    
    id: screen_manager
    screen_thermo: screen_thermo
    MainScreen:
    ScreenThermo:
        id: screen_thermo
        name: 'thermo'
        manager: screen_manager

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    Label:
        text: "Welcome"
        font_size: 60
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'middle'
        pos_hint: {'x': .01, 'y': .05}
        on_touch_down: app.root.current = "thermo"



<ScreenThermo>:
    Label:
        text: " Pulse rate"
        font_size: 50
        pos: (35, 100)


    Label:
        id: TempLabel
        font_size: 60
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'middle'
```

Comment: I'm not clear what your problem is - do you know how to read your sensor? What is preventing you from using the values you get in the Kivy app?

Comment: Yes, I can read the sensor. The `print ('BPM: {}'.format(BPM))` part in the **heartbeatsensot.py** displays the pulse rate in python program. However, what I can't understand is that how to display it in the kivy app that I've created in **another.py**.

Comment: What's preventing me from using the values i get in the Kivy app:  I made a kivy app to display and continuously update the values from the sensors. It works fine with the other sensors but it's not working with the pulse rate sensor and I fail to understand what I'm doing wrong. The only difference between the other sensors and the heartbeat sensor is that I usually extract the value using a python function in others but in this case, I'm doing it by simply printing the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can accomplish what you want with a few minor modifications. First add a `StringProperty` to your `ScreenThermo` class, and in the `on_enter()` method start a thread to run your `Heartbeatsensot` code as:

```
from Heartbeatsensot import hearbeatsensot

class ScreenThermo(Screen):
    BPM_string = StringProperty('BPM: Not Detected')

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Thread(target=hearbeatsensot, args=(self,)).start()
```

And in your `kv` file, add a reference to the new `StringProperty`:

```
<ScreenThermo>:
    Label:
        text: " Pulse rate"
        font_size: 50
        pos: (35, 100)


    Label:
        id: TempLabel
        text: root.BPM_string  # references new StringProperty
        font_size: 60
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'middle'
```

Now you only need to put whatever you want to display in the `TempLabel` into the `BPM_string` property. To do that, change `Heartbeatsensot.py` to define a method that can be used in a `Thread`. Simply replace the `if __name__ == '__main__':` in that file to `def hearbeatsensot(screenThermo):` like this:

```
import time
# Import the ADS1x15 module.
import Adafruit_ADS1x15


def hearbeatsensot(screenThermo):

    adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1015()
    # initialization
    GAIN = 2/3
    .
    .
    .
    screenThermo.BPM_string = 'BPM: 65'
    .
    .
    .
```

Then, within that method just use somethink like `screenThermo.BPM_string = 'BPM: 65'` (or whatever you want to set it to). The reference to `BPM_string` in the `kv` file will automatically set up a binding to update the `TempLabel` whenever `BPM_string` is modified.

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to help me out. I've made the modifications you suggested. However, it returns the following error now:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "heartsensor.py", line 140, in <module>
     presentation = Builder.load_file("heartk.kv")
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 368, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 392, in __init__
     self.parse(content)```

Comment: ```File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 501, in parse
     objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 664, in parse_level
     if current_property[:3] == 'on_':
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: Looks like it is complaining about something in your `kv` file.

Comment: With a few minor changes, I was able to make this to work. Thanks so much for helping!